# empty default component name is displayed as 'Unspecified'

Tags: cmake, cpack

I'm trying to make two packages using cmake 2.8.12: the first one contains a shared library, the second one contains headers files. Apparently, I want two packages with names `libname` and `libname-dev` respectively, so I used command `install` with no specified component for the shared library and the same command with `COMPONENT dev` for the headers files. Before this I had defined an empty default component name. So I have a code as follows:

```
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_DEFAULT_COMPONENT_NAME "")
install(TARGETS libname DESTINATION /usr/local/lib)
install(FILES ${header_files} DESTINATION /usr/local/include COMPONENT dev)
```

But as a result, despite the empty default component name `libname-Unspecified` and `libname-dev` are generated. I find this behavior quite weird, because it seems I have no way to define two packages with previously described names. Are there any ideas how to do this in any other way?

Comment: Did you generate a target for libname? Please post something more of your CMakeLists.txt file

Comment: @Antonio, of course. Moreover, if I set any "blah-blah" instead of an empty name in CMAKE_INSTALL_DEFAULT_COMPONENT_NAME, it works as it's supposed to. Anyway, here is a bit simplified CMakeLists.txt: [http://pastebin.com/rvz7dqJm](http://pastebin.com/rvz7dqJm)

Answer (score 0):

In case of debian:

Give your main component some temporary name, e.g. "runtime".

```
install(TARGETS my-target
    COMPONENT runtime
    DESTINATION ${INSTALLDIR}
)
```

Then remove the postfixed component name as follows:

```
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_RUNTIME_PACKAGE_NAME "${CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME}")
```

Might work with other generators, too if they provide something equivalent to "CPACK_DEBIAN_RUNTIME_PACKAGE_NAME".